# Redirect email based on a script (after-queue) in Postfix?

Tags: queue, postfix-mta

My company would like to implement some rules regarding the email we receive.

The rules are sophisticated enough to not work directly in mail aliases, and we'd like the implementation to work on any email, on any domain we own (which mean if we buy a new domain and point the MX to our server, it should work almost directly).

An example of rules would be something like :

-> We create an email like "support@*" (@* will mean that it works on any domain we point to our server) in the database, and specify which users (with their personal email, like gmail.com / hotmail.com etc) will receive the email. Our support team also indicate in the database when they work (Monday, Tuesday for example), and the script will dispatch the incoming email to our support team based on their workload, their availability, etc.

Based on this kind of complexity, I believe the best option is to implement an `after-queue content filter`, and from what I've seen, I can implement almost everything except the last part : redirecting the email.

**My question is rather simple** : is it possible, in postfix after-queue, to return something that says to postfix "this email is accepted, but you must **redirect** it to outside@another-provider.com", and if so, how to do it?

Moreover, if the email we receive is a lot of spam (because we will indicate the email in clear in our website), will our MX server will be considered spam relay by other webmails (like gmail, hotmail, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

- To have `support@` address for all your domains and redirecting them to your support members, consider the following example.

  ```
  #/etc/postfix/main.cf
  virtual_alias_domains = a.com b.com c.com d.com
  virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps

  #/etc/postfix/vmaps
  support@a.com     auser@gmail.com,buser@hotmail.com
  support@b.com     cuser@sify.com
  support@c.com     duser@somedomain.tld,fuser@gmail.com,huser@hotmail.com
  ```

In the above example, mail to `support@a.com` will always go to `auser@gmail.com` and `buser@hotmail.com`. As you said, if you want to dynamically decide the users, you can write an `SQL function` to achieve the same, because anyway you will have all your domains and users info in some database.

```
    # Sample SQL Function logic
    select support users for that domain who are working on that weekday
    if found return them
    else return default_user who will have to receive mail
```

- Adding email in website, will our `MX` be considered Spam

  If you add your email in website, you may become target for spam attacks. There will be no issues until you send out spam from your servers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way I need to implement it is, I believe, to not use virtual_alias_* because they want to be able to add domains from the database. I was expecting more regarding the part with SQL because it's what I want to achieve, but I don't know if I cant return a message to postfix that says "this email is ok, but redirect it to this external address instead"

Comment: Again both of your requirements are already met. If you use database maps for  `virtual_alias_domains` then u can add domains to database directly and postfix will see it. The above `vmaps` redirect mails to other email addresses already. So if u need them to go to the email address for which the mail came for,then u have to return that email address itself as a result of the lookup. Hope you got it?